# How to hide buyer email from new order email Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to delete buyer email addres from new order email notification.
I have a multivendor solution site and I don't allow vendors to see buyer email.
How to edit woocommerce email template to do this ?
Thanks :)

Comment: Do you want to remove email id  from billing address in email ?

Comment: Yes I think I found right code on Stack overflow but I cant find it anymore :(

Comment: what plugin are you using for multi vendor shop ? i haven't used it before

Comment: I solved problem i add this code to hide all cusomer data in email.
function removing_customer_details_in_emails( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ){
    $wmail = WC()->mailer();
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', array( $wmail, 'email_addresses' ), 20, 3 );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', 'removing_customer_details_in_emails', 5, 4 );

Comment: glad you got the solution